# How to store a value as a global variable that is specific to the user?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently working on a small flask app that will be connecting to an api and processing data pulled from that api.

Users are able to login to my flask app and then also define their credentials to interact with the api. Any given user may have one or more API credentials associated with their user.

I've created db models to store user and Api credentials in the database as follows.

I'm using the flask-login module which has the "**current_user**" object which provides me with the User model of the user that is currently logged in across my entire app.

Models:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(55))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(55))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    creds = db.relationship('ApiCredential', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')

class ApiCredential(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'api_credentials'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    site = db.Column(db.String(140))
    user = db.Column(db.String(140))
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(55))
    base = db.Column(db.String(100))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

I would like to know how to create a similar "global variable" for my API credentials that is specific only to the logged in user and not to all users of the application

NOTE*** It seems as though "current_user" is something called a local proxy which i am not at all familiar with and cannot seem to find any decent documentation or explanation of what it is and how to use it for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You're in for a fun ride, at the end of which you might choose to do something less magic.

First, it helps to understand how `current_user` works. The source (as of this moment) is [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/utils.py#L26). It's a `werkzeug.local.LocalProxy`, which wraps a lambda that calls `flask_login.utils._get_user`.

`LocalProxy` is pretty cool, and understanding it is a great way to level-up on Python, but flask-login uses a thin slice of it. The source (as of this moment) is [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py). It looks scary, but if you trace the code, it merely invokes the local arg (the lambda from flask-login).

That gets us back to `_get_user` ([here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/utils.py#L344), as of this moment), which loads a user if there isn't one (in the top of the current request context), and then returns the user from the top of the request context.

You could follow that pattern, and write a package that exports `current_credentials`. You'd follow the same pattern, using a `werkzeug.local.LocalProxy` to wrap a lambda that invoked, say, `_get_credentials`. The trick would be to import `current_user` from `flask-login`, using it with `_get_credentials` to get to user with which to construct the query to join to your `ApiCredentials` table.

Or you could take a simple approach, and write utility method for your views to use, which would use `current_user` to get the user and then do the join to get API credentials for that user.

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to create a new route in your flask app, when the user `get` requests the page then you can check which user it is, once you know which user it is, you can query using your api credentials model and filter by current_user.id.

```
creds = ApiCredentials.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.id).first_or_404()
```

Then you can do as you please with the information stored in your API Credentials table.

I don't see why you would want to replicate the user loader functionality. This is the function you will have included at some point when you set up Flask login. Very short function that returns the current user object from the user model.

You could display or return your api keys. Display them on a page as HTML or for more autonomous jobs, you could use jsonify to return the keys as a json string.

I'm sorry this doesn't directly answer your question, but I hope my suggestion might lead you to a slightly less complex answer and you can continue developing your web app. Perhaps it would be worth revisiting at a later date.

Note: this is off the top of my head. The code line I provided might need to be as follows

```
creds = ApiCredentials.query.filter_by(owner_id==current_user.id).first()
```

Furthermore, you may not want to use `.first()` if they have multiple api credentials stored in the table.

In which case this would be more suitable:

```
creds = ApiCredentials.query.filter_by(owner_id==current_user.id).all()
```

Comment: i get what you're saying and perhaps it's over kill to store in the session if i already have the user id and can just query the db. But in your last suggestion, that query would return multiple credentials, I would only be interested in the active one or the selected one.

Comment: I actually edited that part in after the answer, I understand your point, but was trying to satisfy your requirement to check against a user with multiple api keys stored. In which case, I suggest that you make that part of the request that you get sent by the client, a piece of data your api hook can expect that will identify which key from the .all() statement it should be using. Without that, do nothing.